# HTML Button Function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, repeat

I know how to create a button in HTML but how would I create a JavaScript 
function that when the button is pressed it keeps creating multiple buttons and just keeps adding them to the screen?

```
   <script>
    function repeats() {
            ?
    }
   </script
   <input id ="addsubmit"  type="submit" value= "Submit" style = "margin-top: 25px;">
   </input>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried anything yet.  Please do so, or if you have, show us what you've tried.  Otherwise it looks like you're asking for free code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - please let me know is this what you asked for :-)

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    function repeats() {
        document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML += '<input id ="addsubmit" onclick="repeats()";  type="submit" value= "Submit" style = "margin-top: 25px;">';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <input id ="addsubmit" onclick="repeats()";  type="submit" value= "Submit" style = "margin-top: 25px;">
     </input>
     <div  id="buttons">buttons here: </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @salihOvicX Yea that works, what does the innerHTML mean in the function?

Comment: @HomerHomer The inner HTML of the tag.